# Check if model found anything in SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, left-join

I am looking for way how to do left outer join that returns row either if right table returns None or if entry exists, some column is equal to some value. For example:

```
session.query(
    Teacher, Student
).outerjoin(
    Student, Teacher.subject == Student.subject
).filter(
    or_(
        Student.name == "Mark",
        # no student was found and query should return (teacher, None)
    ),
    Teacher.name == 'John'
).all()
```

Is it possible to do such query?

Tried  Student.is_(None) but is_() can be only called on column not model as whole.

Answer (score 0):

Well hackfixed it by `Student.id.is_(None)` but I wonder if there is better solution :)